# Find main method in IJavaProject

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse plugin development, is there any suitable way to find the main method(if any) in the project, which is in IJavaProject type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the JDT [Search Engine](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_search.htm?cp=3_0_0_4) from `org.eclipse.jdt.core`. For the search scope, you can use the `IJavaProject` itself wrapped in an array.